# Using global variable to call function

Tags: ruby, function

I wad told to use brackets. I get the following behaviour when using a variable to call a function. From what I've read in the documentation, brackets aren't supposed to make any difference.

I have this:

```rb
def pr (arg1, arg2)
  if arg2
    puts arg1
  end
end
```

This code results in unexpected `','` in front of the `false`, but without brackets, it works.

```rb
for i in 1...4
  pr (i,false)
end
```

This works:

```rb
for i in 1...4 
  pr i,false
end
```

Comment: In Ruby 2.3+ you should get an error of the form "syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'" which would alert you to a problem. Are you using an older version of Ruby? I know older versions were a lot more permissive here, but the ambiguity caused a lot of problems like what you're seeing.

Comment: Another thing to note is while Ruby has a `for`, it doesn't normally get used. Instead, consider: `4.times do |i|` (zero-indexed) or `1.upto(4) do |i|` where you have a lot more control over how things iterate that way.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does this have to do with global variables? There is not a single global variable in your code, what makes you think the problem is related to global variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove space before brackets and your code will work fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

def pr(arg1, arg2)
  if arg2
    puts arg1
  end
end

for i in 1...4
  pr(i, false)
end
```

Use either space or brackets before arguments list, never both.

Comment: Thats it. Thank you